# Why do Espresso tests fail to launch with NoClassDefFoundError PlatformTestStorageRegistry?

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso, androidx

I am trying to update the gradle `androidTestImplementation` dependencies of my project. I am using the latest recommendations from the [androidx.test releases page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/test) which at the time of writing are:

```
// UI Testing
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.5.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.5.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.4"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:monitor:1.6.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.5.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.5.0"
```

My Espresso tests used to launch OK, but although the tests compile fine now the launch hangs and I see:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/PlatformTestStorageRegistry
```

This is the stack trace:

```
15:23:14.293 AndroidRuntime           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                         Process: <my bundle id>, PID: <pid>
                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/PlatformTestStorageRegistry;
                                            at androidx.test.internal.runner.RunnerArgs$Builder.<init>(RunnerArgs.java:248)
                                            at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.parseRunnerArgs(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:393)
                                            at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onCreate(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:302)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6726)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:256)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2090)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
  ...
```

I have found this issue which sounds similar: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1315 so I have tried this in my `build.gradle`, but it makes no difference.

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:monitor:1.6.0") {
    transitive = false
}
```

I have tried clean project and invalidate caches.

How do you debug this kind of problem? What is a compatible set of test packages?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? We also face the issue, and had to downgrad espresso to 3.4.0

Comment: I didn't; like you I stuck with espresso 3.4.0. I'll try again next time there's an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I had the same issue and what did the trick for me was adding this monitor dependency specifically as `debugImplementation` to `build.gradle` instead of using `androidTestImplementation`.

```
debugImplementation "androidx.test:monitor:1.6.0"
```

Source: [github](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1589#issuecomment-1316971699)